# Facebook Like Button is not displaying in OS X Yosemite MacBook pro - Retina in FireFox?

Tags: facebook, macos

I created a page and I want to display the Facebook like button. So I used the below code :

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/samplePageName" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

For all the devices the Facebook Like button displaying Perfectly, Except OS X Yosemite MacBook pro - Retina. How to resolve this ?